# Что происходит в данной рекурсии?

Tags: python, рекурсия

Задача найти сумму цифр числа, рекурсивно повторять пока результат не станет однозначным числом.

Рекурсия, это вызов функцией самой себя, вроде я сделал так. Но функция не возвращает никакого значения, в то же время, если заменить return на print() получиться правильное значение. Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит в данной функции, почему она ничего не возвращает и почему моя рекурсия не правильна.

```
def digital_root(n):
    lst = [int(i) for i in list(str(n))]
    if len(lst) > 1:
        result = sum(lst)
        digital_root(result)
    else:
        return print(lst[0])
```

Comment: «почему она ничего не возвращает» — потому что у вас return стоит только в ветке else, а если условие `if len(lst) > 1` истинно, то ветка else не выполняется, значит никакой return тоже не выполняется и соответственно ничего не возвращается. А ещё функция `print` ничего не возвращает, а значит `return print(...)` тоже не будет ничего возвращать

Comment: А вообще функцию можно записать в одну строку (предполагая, что число целое неотрицательное) — `digital_root = lambda n: n if n < 10 else digital_root(sum(int(x) for x in str(n)))`

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение!